# how to load website (google, yahoo, any site) to canvas

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

how to load website (google, yahoo, any site) to canvas

Comment: If you want better help, ask a better question.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Adobe AIR and its HTML control to do this. Flex cannot easily render large, complicated HTML documents.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/HTML.html

Answer (score 0):

Very simply the following:

```
<mx:HTML location="(url of the HTML)"/>
```

For all other properties and events check the page Brd6644 linked.